# How do i set the relative path and folder paths in HTML and CSS from VS 2012?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-2012

i'm creating a simple HTML site with `css` and `javascript`. so there are folders named **css** and **scripts** also **images** for images. the Project structure is like in this image

[image]

The problem i have is how to set the paths for the **css**, **images** and **js** files from the html

i have styles.css file with the following style

```
html {
padding-top: 25px;  
background-image: url(images/bg_page.png);
```

}

the link to styles.css file from html like this

```
<title>Chapter 2</title>
<link  href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gravitas+One" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**problem**: it doesn't set the styles in the **css** to the **html**. I don't know how to set the image URL path in css as well. Any one who uses VS 2012, would be able to fix this path problems?

There is this "solution1" folder that it creates, which is kind of annoying. so i wonder is there a better way to organize folders and files especially in VS 2012?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that you set up different folders? Just because the solution shows different folders doesn't mean that actual folders have been created. Check your source folder to make sure.

If the folders exist, try adding `/` before `images` in `background-image` in your css.

Comment: it was folders, that the folder were not created. so i manually created them!

Comment: Haha I had the same problem once, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your stylesheet must reference files relative to the stylesheet's folder, NOT the folder of the HTML.

You therefore want:
background-image: url(../images/bg_page.png);